# TinyMCE divs editable in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Internet Explorer is giving layout to my DIVs in TinyMCE.
This means that when a user starts editing all the text in the div is selected, rather than the cursor being inserted in the desired position, and it has editable drag handles:

Screenshot: http://puu.sh/knI67/c5c7250e56.png

Can I add some JQuery to my page, or to the TinyMCE init() to move the cursor to the desired position when the user clicks inside the div?

It's fine in Chrome, Firefox. Latest version of Tiny MCE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what css do you have in your editor.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked around it by wrapping in a contenteditable=false div, and then adding contenteditable=true to the other divs inside the editor. Seems to work.